# How to send push notifications to specific contact phone number registered user in firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'll narrate an instance where, a registered current user(let me) I have a contact list that is from my device now I need to send a specific text as a notification to a person who's in my contact list and also consider that he is registered to the same app otherwise I can invite him/her.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on regestration time you can store contact num and FCM token to database when you want to send a notification Query Token using `where contact number= your selected cantact` and send notification to that previsously query token and if no data exist then you can share invite link

[here is about token] (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options)

Answer (score 0):

Use FCM to send messages to specific devices.Google FCM for more information regarding it.